# Routing public / external IP to docker container

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am running coreos with flanneld. A single host, may have multiple containers running a web server on port 80. I would like to route a static ip to a container.

Architecture would be as follows.

Docker Host (CoreOS) internal IP of 10.20.0.1
This host has 3 nginx containers, sitting at
- 172.16.20.1
- 172.16.20.2
- 172.16.20.3

My Google cloud VPC is only specified at the host network level, the docker network is specified within the coreos etcd2 cluster with flannel.

I want to reserve, a static ip address and route all traffic to/from the public ip, to one of the container ip addresses.

eg; 104.89.255.255 (public) <--> 172.16.20.1

Is this possible at all on GCE?

I am able to achieve this internally, with my site to site vpn. However, some of the sites on the containers need to be accessed publicly.

Any direction provided is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You cant currently attach multiple external IPs to a single VM, but you can use a load balancer instead and have it send traffic to your VM but to different ports for your different services.

The HTTP Load Balancer can easily host all of your sites behind the same IP and steer traffic based on the host-header or the path of the request.

More documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/